# Merging PHP Arrays for JSON output

Tags: php, arrays, json

I'm having a difficult time trying to get back a single array, which I can then return as JSON.

The Model:

```
class CoverageLimit extends Eloquent {

    protected $table = 'webapp_limit_tbl';

    public static function index($code,$plan_type,$income_tier){
        $data =  CoverageLimit::where('limitcode', $code)
        ->where('plantypecode', $plan_type)
        ->where('incometiercode', $income_tier)
        ->get(array('limitcode','limit_desc'));
        return print_r($data->toArray());
    }

}
```

The Controller:

```
$limits = array();
    foreach($pieces as $coverage_limit) {
    $limits = array_merge($limits, coveragelimit::index($coverage_limit,$plan_type,$income_tier));
//this now works thanks to suggestion below
    } 
return $limits;
```

Returns:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [limitcode] => L0001
            [limit_desc] => $1M per claim / $2M annual aggregate
        )

)
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [limitcode] => L0002
            [limit_desc] => $2M per claim/ $2M annual aggregate
        )

)
[true,true]
```

The goal is to output the following JSON data via json_encode($limits):

`[{"limitcode":"L0001","limit_desc":"$1M per claim / $2M annual aggregate"},{"limitcode":"L0002","limit_desc":"$2M per claim / $2M annual aggregate"}`]

I think what I need is a single array like below in order to accomplish this, but I can't seem to make it happen.

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [limitcode] => L0001
            [limit_desc] => $1M per claim / $2M annual aggregate
        ),
    [1] => Array
        (
            [limitcode] => L0002
            [limit_desc] => $2M per claim/ $2M annual aggregate
        )

)
```

I would be grateful for any help on how I could merge this return into a single array for valid json output. Or if there is a way to return it from the foreach as one array. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, do not use `return print_r($data->toArray());`

That is incorrect. Just do `return $data->toArray()` and it should work just fine.

The problem is that print_r returns a boolean and outputs to stdout a text representation of your data structure. That is why you see that annoying [true, true] at the end of your output example. The array you are attempting to json_encode is actually just an array with two values of true returned from print_r.

Comment: Thank you, that was the ticket!